# Invoke a Maven artifact from a Bash script, passing arbitrary arguments?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-exec-plugin

The aim is to have a Bash script that runs a Java program from a project that is built with Maven, ideally with a classpath that uses all the JARs needed from the Maven cache.

I can think of two solutions for this, but they are all a bit ugly or cannot deal with certain problems:

1) use the `exec:java` plugin/goal. The problem I could not solve there is that one cannot pass arbitrary arguments to the program from the command line with this solution: the only way to pass arguments is by setting the value of a `mvn` command line argument. So if there are several arguments, that value needs to be quoted. However if the arguments to pass to the program need quoting and e.g. option values can contain spaces, there seems to be no way to do this.

2) use the dependency plugin to create a file that contains the classpath using the `build-classpath` goal. This is brilliant to generate a file that contains the locations of all JARs in the Maven cache, which the project depends on. However, it seems to be impossible to also add the location of the project artifact JAR to that file. So the content from this file needs to get combined with the location of the project JAR somehow:

2.1) use `mvn package` and use the JAR in `target` directory. This is ugly because ideally we would also want to use the JAR from the Maven cache, like for the dependencies

2.2) have another dummy Maven project that depends on the one which I want to run and use the `build-classpath` goal there. This will then give me the full classpath, but at the cost of needing to have another project and run the necessary goals in that project. If the project is in a subdirectory of the original project, I can also see no nice way of how to build that fake project as part of the main project except maybe using the `exec:exec` plugin/goal, which is ugly.

Is there anything I am missing or a recommended way of how to do this in a more straightforward way?

UPDATE: I was asked in the comments why I want to use the Maven cache in the first place. The reason is that in this context, we know that everything needed is already in the maven cache, we are talking about rather large dependency chains and it would feel very awkward and clumsy to use a different mechanism and different cache, just in order to make this work. It is hard to understand why Maven does not provide an easier solution to this right away.

Comment: The question is why you explicitly asking for using the maven cache to run? There is a plugin appassembler-maven-plugin which can generate the script including the whole repository/list of libs which are needed to run the app? Or you can use maven-assembly-plugin to create a ueber jar / maven shade is also an option?

Comment: Because I know all the jars and all the dependencies are already in the cache. This is because the jars are mainly for a GUI which uses Maven for its plugin and dynamic download management, but there are a few components where command-line usage should be supported. So ideally, the same mechanisms and the same storage for the JARs should get used there.